# Apostrophe turning to question mark when using PHP handler in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an .htm page on a site, that for reasons I won't go into cannot be renamed to `.php`.

I have added some PHP code to the top of the page(, which sets a cookie and redirects to another page) and added the following to the `.htaccess` to parse the `.htm` file as PHP:

```
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

As soon as this is added to `.htacces`s all apostrophe's change into questions marks. I am using charset UTF-8.

Can anyone offer a solution that does not involve renaming the file `.php`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophes are most likely not the regular apostrophe character you think they are (ascii 39). They might be a funky character produced in a word processor and pasted in. Open the file in your favorite editor and backspace over the fake apostrophes and retype a plain apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

If your server allows you to use *.php* files and you simply want to preserve the url, you can use mod_rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^myfilename\.htm$ myfilename.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```